# Is it possible to use GPU to boost performance of computer automatically?

Tags: cpu, gpu, parallel-processing

As we all know GPU is a sleeping beast. And we are also familiar with Intel's Turbo Boost technology which is really great.

But, Intel's Turbo Boost technology works only on CPU by overclocking CPU automatically when there is an overload.

I was wondering, it would be great if we can use GPU automatically to support CPU whenever there is an overload.

I don't know if there is research going on this topic cause I found nothing (may be I haven't used proper keywords). So, please let me know if it is possible.

Comment: GPU is good for one thing floating point computations.  Besides this is already done.  You use a GPU to perform these computations because its faster at them then the CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GPU does different kind of computation to the CPU, often matrix transformations and floating point computations. The sole purpose of the GPU is to support the CPU when handling complex display computations. When the GPU gets used will be dependent on drivers and the software itself (the software may request all computation be done on the CPU alone).

Turboboost is completely different and it (safely) overlocks the CPU to perform faster when the load increases.

Btw, on the new Core i chips from intel, the GPU and CPU are on the same die and there is no reason for them to not internally share load automatically, see http://anandtech.com/show/8814/intel-releases-broadwell-u-new-skus-up-to-48-eus-and-iris-6100/2.